# Class function not working in main - SDL

Tags: function, class, sdl, program-entry-point, simulator

I am trying to make a sort of bouncing ball simulator. I have separate classes for the ball, however I have a problem. If i call (for example) the Ball class function myBall.show() in main, the ball doesn't show. However, if in main, I write out the function in full, instead of just myBall.show(), it works. Anyway to fix this issue, its happening for other functions as well.

Main.cpp

```
// Ball Simulator.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Globals(BallSim).h"
#include "Ball.h"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


Ball myBall;//ball that will be used for the program

while (quit == false)//game loop, while user hasnt quit
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) //while there is an event to handle
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    //show the ball
    myBall.show();//THIS DOESNT WORK, EVEN THOUGH LINE BELOW IS SAME
    //SDL_BlitSurface(BallSurface, NULL, ScreenSurface, &posBall);//THIS WORKS

    //move the ball
    myBall.move();//THIS DOESNT WORK
            SDL_BlitSurface(Ball, NULL, ScreenSurface, &posBall); //THIS WORKS


    //update the window
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(Window);

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just too much code. Narrow it down to a small example.

Comment: ive taken a lot out now

Comment: Obviously the problem is not with the SDL library but the programming logic. Try coding up a small test example without any libraries to determine the problem.

Comment: Then you can post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) example as a new question.

Comment: Are you using a separate implementation file for Ball.h, and if so is it being included by your compiler?  Please post an SSCCE so we can be of more help.